# Can I parse XML in an AsyncTask right after making a HttpPost to retrieve it? Using SAX parse

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, android-asynctask

This might seem like a bit of a basic question but I've sort of confused myself, going around in circles based on tutorials.

I have to do an authorization in my HttpPost with a `Hmac_Sha-1` code, add it to the header. The XML comes back just fine but obviously it's not parsed. The AsyncTask is in it's own class i.e `extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>.`

Is there a way to Parse it straight after? Maybe if I put the result into a string? I'm just unsure if it all can be done right there and then, much like JSON can be parse right there. Obviously that's different though.

Tutorials show lots of classes are needed. The reason for doing this is because I want to run the HttpPost request the second my app starts, get the request and hopefully parse it, then use an interface listener or whatever to send it to the correct Fragment.

A lot of the tutorials have done `InputStream is = readerXML.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));` which I can't do because I need to add a header to my post request otherwise I won't even return an XML to parse. At least to my knowledge.

This is more of a theory question but it will get me in the direction I need.

Appreciate any help!
Thank you.

**EDIT:** Typical, just post a question and basically find half my answer. I can parse the string I get from my HttpPost in my SAXParser and I can do it in the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can. I think everyone knows how to do this, I just call my DefaultHandler class within my AsyncTask right after I have done a HTTP request. That will will then throw out an ArrayList in the onPostExecute which I can work with. Basically how everyone does it... I just didn't catch on.